# Copy row values based on drop down to the column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to fill in values from the table on the Sheet 2 (rows) based on the cell value on the Sheet 1 (it's dropdown list) and copy these values to the Sheet 1 as column (the same order).
There is a table on the Sheet 2 range B3:H18 and the first column (B3:B18) is used as data for drop down list in the cell I2 on the Sheet 1. I need to copy table data in the row range C:H (Sheet 2) matched to the value from the dropdown list (Sheet 1) to the column range D15:D20 (Sheet 1).
I know I can use VLOOKUP function but the problem is, that the values in the column on the Sheet 1 can be overwritten with custom input. Can anyone help me to solve this problem, please? Any help would be really appreciated!

[Sheet 1 with drop down list and table where to copy the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPAW9.jpg)
[Sheet 2 with source data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLt7l.jpg)

```
        Sub Company_selection()
Dim RngToCopy As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 
Dim ws3 As Worksheet: Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
ws3.Range("B3:H18").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("B3:H18").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ws1.Range("I2")
    Set RngToCopy = Selection.Offset(-1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Selection.AutoFilter
    RngToCopy.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D15:D20")

Exit Sub
  End Sub
```

Comment: If you have access to the `FILTER` function this is very easy

Comment: Otherwise, if you are looking for VBA then just use `Range.Filter` and then work with the resultant set from filter (`SpecialCells xlCellTypeVisible`) to copy etc.

Comment: Could you help me with the VBA as I'm quite new in it? I know how to do it with the function but the problem is that the target cells can be overwritten.

Comment: Of course I was trying to create own code but I can't get it working:

Comment: If you need to add code you can edit your question to add it there - code in comments is not very readable.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your comment. I did it from my cell phone, so my mistake.

Comment: So you expect always only one row to match?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. All values in the first column are unique. So no need to make a loop and go through the all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's only one expected match (all values in Col1 are unique) then you can use Match

This goes in the code module for ws1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I2")) Is Nothing Then
        Company_selection
    End If
End Sub
```

...and in a regular module:

```
Sub Company_selection()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet: Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    Dim tbl As ListObject, m, v

    v = ws1.Range("I2").Value
    If Len(v) > 0 Then

        Set tbl = ws3.ListObjects(1)
        Debug.Print "looking for '" & v & "' in sheet '" & ws3.Name & "' " & _
                tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Address()

        m = Application.Match(ws1.Range("I2").Value, _
                              tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0)

        If Not IsError(m) Then
             Debug.Print "Found " & v
             ws1.Range("D15:D20").Value = _
               Application.Transpose(tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(m, 2).Resize(1, 6).Value)
        Else
            'no match
            Debug.Print v & " was not found"
        End If
    Else
        ws1.Range("D15:D20").ClearContents 'clear data if no selection
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: William, 
I'm sorry for my late reply, it was already 4 in the morning here. But anyway thanks a lot. But somehow I cannot make it working. When I change any value in the cell "I2" nothing happens. I tried to play around to define Table1 (that's the table range B3:H18 on the Sheet3), rename sheets but still nothing.

Comment: How are you running the code?  I added a few debug.prints  - see if those give you a clue

Comment: It would be triggered by changing the value in the cell "I2". I finally found one mistake. There was a wrong sheet name. So now I'm able to run the code via macro. What am I doing wrong to trigger it by changing value in the cell?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and effort  to solve this problem. I do hope it will help to somebody else.

Comment: If you want it to run automatically then you'd need to use the worksheet_change event in ws1 to call this code.  See my edit above.

Comment: Could you please check my code above. I have the issue to make it working correctly. When I change the value in the "N18" nothing happens. I have to change value in "Q:Q" range to project the change in the cells "R". I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@TIM I was trying to looking for change in the "L18" or range of "Q15:Q28" but it only works if I make a change in the range "Q15:Q28". What am I missing?

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Res As Variant
       If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L18, Q15:Q28")) Is Nothing Then
          Res = Evaluate("INDEX(N18,MATCH(" & Target.Address & ",J18,0))")
          If Not IsError(Res) Then Target.Offset(, 1) = Res
       End If

End Sub
```

[this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDmoq.jpg)

Comment: @TimWilliams I added PrtScn to explain it. There is a dorp down list in "L18" with days "1d, 2d, 3d ...etc.". This block of code is checking, if I change the this value from the drop down list and calculates it if the appropriate selection is made in the range "Q15:Q28" (so in the column right of this cell).

Comment: Worksheet_change is only triggered if you make a change directly - it doesn't respond to changes in cell values which contain a formula.  You could instead monitor L18 and M18 for changes.

Comment: @TimWilliams I add one line at the beginning of the block of code but it still doesn't work. That was actually first idea but as it didn't work I tried another way.

Comment: @TimWilliams I was trying to looking for change in the "L18" respectively in the "N18" or range of "Q15:Q28". But it only works if I make a change in the range "Q15:Q28". What am I missing? I tried many different ways how to do it but it always end up with the same result. I also tried to make separate sub code with the link from Worksheet_Change but this end with "Error 424 Object Required".

Comment: Can you please start a new question with all of the relevant code?  There's too much here now to follow - also don't post answers as new questions: if you have a follow-up question you can edit your original question to add new content.

Comment: @TimWilliams I did so to make it clear:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62379260/change-of-cell-value-doesnt-trigger-required-function