# Change of cell value doesn't trigger required function

Tags: excel, vba

There is a drop down list in "L18" with days "1d, 2d, 3d ...etc.". This block of code is checking, if I change the value from the drop down list and calculates it or if the appropriate selection is made in the range "Q15:Q28" (so in the column right of this cell).
Simply it should check if there is a change in the cell "L18" or the range "Q15:Q28" and triggers changing value in the range right from "Q15:Q28" But it only works if I make a change in the range "Q15:Q28". What am I missing? If I change the value in the drop down list in "L18" nothing happens.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I2")) Is Nothing Then
        Company_selection
    End If

Dim Res As Variant
       If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L18:L22, Q15:Q28")) Is Nothing Then
          Res = Evaluate("INDEX(N18:N24,MATCH(" & Target.Address & ",J18:J24,0))")
          If Not IsError(Res) Then Target.Offset(, 1) = Res
       End If

    End Sub
```

[Table PrtScn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhyk3.jpg)

Comment: What is the Evaluate intended to do?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm sorry, I attached wrong PrtScn. I edited it and it's ok now.
But basically there is help cell "N18" with "PRODUCT" function to calculate "L18*M18". But the value "L18" can be change as it's dropdown list. And the range "Q15:Q28" includes also drop down lists where if value matches (Aircraft Idle Days "J18" = Aircraft Idle Days "Qxx") it triggers this change as well.

Comment: @Nuficek - I'm not sure that answers Tim's question though. What is the point of the `Evaluate` and `INDEX/MATCH`?

Comment: @BigBen This is just simple example. The real table has much more rows. That's why I have to search in the whole range to match the condition.

Comment: Sure, but your INDEX/MATCH doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: "This is just simple example" - we can handle something more complex: when you over-simplify, your code eventually stops making sense, as in this example where you have a formula which seems to do nothing...

Comment: I changed my question and attached new code and the PrtScn to show why I use INDEX/MATCH. I do hope it's clear from the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Nuficek,

I simplified your code to the part giving you the problem, inserted a dropdown in L18 and it worked. As did making changes anywhere in the two ranges.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

       If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L18:L22, Q15:Q28")) Is Nothing Then
          MsgBox "Fired"
       End If

End Sub
```

So it would appear that the problem is not with the item firing but rather what you do later. You might want to insert a MsgBox in your code to test out this theory.

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot for your opinion. I suspected that the problem is with the code executing to copy the the value matching criteria. Is there any chance to help me to write it different way as I'm not so experienced in the VBA. I would prefer to avoid using VBA as I'm novice in it. But the problem is always that the value can be overwritten/changed by user so function would be deleted. So I'm trying to make my project with functions only but unfortunately sometimes it's inevitable to ask for help to use VBA

Comment: Nuficek, you can protect cells so the user can't change them. Of course that depends on whether or not you want the user to be able to change them?

Comment: The reason is that it's necessary to have the option to change the value. The user has to have options to enter own value or the value will be preselected based on the criteria in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Nuficek,

You might want to try copying the dropdown value to a another cell say one column left or right of the dropdown.
The user could change their values there also. Then you just adjust your formulas to use those cells and also include them in a third Intersect statement.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

       If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L18:L22")) Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "Fired1"
         Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Value '**Copy one column left
       End If

       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Q15:Q28")) Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "Fired2"
         Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Value
       End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work either (see my answer with the code).

Comment: Nuficek, It seems you have two threads with this same question?

Comment: I was asked by William (from previous thread) to create new thread to make it clear and not mix two questions together.

Comment: Unfortunately, I posted my last solution to the old thread. Check it out there.

Comment: I've already answered you. This is how it should work:

Comment: It doesn't work either. Btw range "N18:N24" is used as help cell with the function e.g. N18=PRODUCT(LEFT(L18,2),M18) -> for example it converts "05 days" to "05" and trigger PRODUCT function "5*M18" and the result is copied to the matching cell next to range "Q18:Q24" (if "J18" matches any cell from range "Q18:Q24" (for example "Q20") then copy "N18" to "R20" (cell left from "J18"). And the whole problem is that it works only if I select value from drop down list in the "Q20". If I change any value in the range "L18:L24" it doesn't work and I have to reselect the value in the "Q20".

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you changed the L18:L22 to N18:N22 should have been left at column L. See comments in code.

```
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L18:L22")) Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "Fired1"
         Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value '**Copy one column left (J)
       End If

       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Q15:Q28")) Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "Fired2"
         Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Value '**Copy one column left (P)
End If

Dim Res As Variant
'       If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub (Redundant already done above)
       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N18:N24, P15:P28")) Is Nothing Then
          Res = Evaluate("INDEX(O18:O24,MATCH(" & Target.Address & ",J18:J24,0))")
'*** Don't know about the ranges above but may need double checking...        
          If Not IsError(Res) Then Target.Offset(, 1) = Res
       End If
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. Btw range "N18:N24" is used as help cell with the function e.g. N18=PRODUCT(LEFT(L18,2),M18) -> for example it converts "05 days" to "05" and trigger PRODUCT function "5*M18" and the result is copied to the matching cell next to range "Q18:Q24" (if "J18" matches any cell from range "Q18:Q24" (for example "Q20") then copy "N18" to "R20" (cell left from "J18"). And the whole problem is that it works only if I select value from drop down list in the "Q20". If I change any value in the range "L18:L24" it doesn't work and I have to reselect the value in the "Q20".

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit the code with help of RetiredGeek but doesn't work either:

```
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N18:N22")) Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "Fired1"
         Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value '**Copy one column left
       End If

       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Q15:Q28")) Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "Fired2"
         Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Value
End If

Dim Res As Variant
       If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N18:N24, P15:P28")) Is Nothing Then
          Res = Evaluate("INDEX(O18:O24,MATCH(" & Target.Address & ",J18:J24,0))")
          If Not IsError(Res) Then Target.Offset(, 1) = Res
       End If
```